# Why AngularJS resource generate an url for get with params instead change url?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

My code:

```
var users = $resource('http://domain.com/subscribers/:userId', { userId: '@id' });
var user = users.get({id: $scope.id}, function(){
    $scope.email = user.email
});
```

My browser sends **http://domain.com/subscribers?id=1** but I need **http://domain.com/subscribers/1** .
What is wrong?

Comment: It should be `users.get({userId: $scope.id}, ..`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put first param empty at call:

```
var user = users.get({}, {id: $scope.id}, function(){
    $scope.email = user.email
});
```

Comment: This might cause a confusion because you pass in the data that suppose to be in HTTP request body, but it's not there in GET request.